# Problemas a consultar datos de la noche PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

Tengo la siguiente consulta para mostrar el promedio de temperatura y humedad relativa de las dos últimas noches a partir de la fecha actual:

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS Fecha, 
       ROUND(AVG(temperature),2)  AS Temperatura, 
       ROUND(AVG(humidity),2)        AS Humedad 
FROM mt_meteorology
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '2016-09-27' AND '2016-09-28'
      AND (TIME(date) > '18:00:00'
      OR DATE(date) BETWEEN '2016-09-28' AND '2016-09-29'
      AND TIME(date) < '06:00:00')
GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

Por ejemplo hoy es `'2016-09-29'`, para consultar los datos de la noche anterior lo tengo en cuenta de la siguiente manera:

La noche del `'2016-09-28'` (que es la anterior) , comprenden los datos desde las `18:00:00` hasta las `23:59:59` del `'2016-09-28'` y los datos desde las `00:00:00` hasta las `06:00:00` del `'2016-09-29'`

Lo mismo con la noche del `'2016-09-27'`, que comprenden los datos desde las `18:00:00` hasta las `23:59:59` del `'2016-09-27'` y los datos entre las `00:00:00` hasta las `06:00:00` del `'2016-09-28'`

El problema es que la consulta no funciona porque lo que hace es promediar los datos entre las mismas fechas sin importar las horas que estoy seteando.

Cómo puedo hacer para promediar los datos de las dos últimas noches con los requerimientos ya anteriormente mencionados.

Gracias.

Comment: Me parece que los paréntesis no están bien puestos.

Comment: Trate cambiando los paréntesis, pero no funciona igual!

Comment: ¿Cómo trataste de cambiar los paréntesis? Porque @Luis tiene razón, están mal puestos y ese será un motivo por el que tu consulta no funcionará

Comment: Solamente los abrí al principio y los cerré al final del `WHERE`

Comment: No, no los abriste al principio del WHERE, los abriste después de la primera condición. Mira mi respuesta con detalles de por qué están los paréntesis mal puestos (lo cual creará también problemas con la precedencia de los operadores O e Y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como bien indica [Luis en un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25487/problemas-a-consultar-datos-de-la-noche-php/25489#comment41351_25487), los paréntesis están mal puestos. Tal y como está ahora la clausula WHERE, estás obteniendo los valores que cumplan con estas condiciones:

- La fecha esté entre '2016-09-27' y '2016-09-28'

  **Y**
- La hora sea mayor que 6pm **O** la fecha entre '2016-09-28' y '2016-09-29' **Y** la hora sea menor que 6am.

Voy a poner aquí tu consulta con formato para que se vea mejor el problema:

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS Fecha, 
       ROUND(AVG(temperature),2)  AS Temperatura, 
       ROUND(AVG(humidity),2)     AS Humedad 
FROM mt_meteorology
WHERE 
       DATE(date) BETWEEN '2016-09-27' AND '2016-09-28'
       AND 
       (
        TIME(date) > '18:00:00'
        OR 
        DATE(date) BETWEEN '2016-09-28' AND '2016-09-29'
        AND  
        TIME(date) < '06:00:00'
       )
GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

---

Cuando realmente lo que quieres es esto:

- La fecha esté entre '2016-09-27' y '2016-09-28' **Y** la hora sea mayor que 6pm;

  **O**
- La fecha esté entre '2016-09-28' y '2016-09-29' **Y** la hora sea menor que 6am.

Por lo que necesitas mover los paréntesis un poco:

```
SELECT DATE(date) AS Fecha, 
       ROUND(AVG(temperature),2)  AS Temperatura, 
       ROUND(AVG(humidity),2)     AS Humedad 
FROM mt_meteorology
WHERE (
       DATE(date) BETWEEN '2016-09-27' AND '2016-09-28'
       AND 
       TIME(date) > '18:00:00'
      )
      OR 
      (
       DATE(date) BETWEEN '2016-09-28' AND '2016-09-29'
       AND 
       TIME(date) < '06:00:00'
      )
GROUP BY DATE(date);
```

Comment: Lo estuve probando y me da los mismos resultados! :(, si tienes razón con lo de los paréntesis, pero me da el mismo resultado

Comment: Independientemente de que haya otro posible fallo. Lo que te pongo en esta respuesta sigue siendo válido y un error en tu consulta original. Otro posible error, aunque creo que no debería ser un problema, es que DATE(date) te devuelve una fecha concreta, por lo que no necesitas hacer el BETWEEN, sino que te valdría directamente con un igual: `(DATE(date) = '2016-09-27'  AND TIME(date) > '18:00:00') OR (DATE(date) = '2016-09-28'  AND TIME(date) < '06:00:00')`'

Comment: Como pones la etiqueta PHP, supongo que estás generando la consulta con ese lenguaje, podrías hacer directamente algo como `WHERE date BETWEEN '2016-09-27 18:00:00' AND '2016-09-28 06:00:00'`, sin necesidad de complicar la consulta con tantas condiciones

Comment: Por cierto, aunque esto ya como recomendación personal y no relacionado con la pregunta en sí, `date` es un mal nombre para una columna/variable en SQL porque es el nombre de una función (y una palabra reservada en algunos sistemas de bases de datos)

Comment: tienes toda la razón sobre el nombre de la columna, sólo que ya no la puedo cambiar porque me implica hacer cambios grandes, y estoy revisando lo que me propones y ya te comento! :)

Comment: Me funcionó, tienes toda la razón esta ubicando mal los paréntesis en la consulta, gracias ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Entonces si la columna se llama date debes agregar comillas simples, como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
SELECT Date(`date`) AS Fecha
FROM stack
WHERE 
    `date` BETWEEN '2016-09-27 18:00:00' AND '2016-09-28 06:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE(Fecha);
```

Realice un ejercicio, pero ahora el problema, es que si tu campo no es `timestamp` o `datetime`, no te podrá obtener datos con la hora.

Comment: En mi caso la columna de la tabla se llama `date`, me genera complicaciones, entonces me toca usar un alias, y el nombre de alias `Fecha`, no lo reconoce en el `WHERE`

Comment: @FabianSierra reemplaza `Fecha` por `date` en el `WHERE` y listo. Esta solución me parece más simple, efectiva y fácil de mantener, a comparación de lo que estabas intentando y que tiene tanto `OR`.

Comment: @FabianSierra Esto acaba siendo más simple, como te sugería en [este comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25487/problemas-a-consultar-datos-de-la-noche-php#comment41360_25489)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza tienes toda la razón tenía bloqueada mi mente! gracias!